# ZFC is not categorical; it is also not complete, does this mean there are multiple candidates for the category $\mathrm{Set}$? How do we pick one out?

Tags: category-theory

I'm interested in understanding the role that $\mathrm{Set}$ plays in the category of categories. Functors going to $\mathrm{Set}$ show up a lot, in contexts including but not limited to discussions of Grothendieck topologies and the Yoneda lemma. I'm interested in picking $\mathrm{Set}$ out uniquely or perhaps up to isomorphism and the technical issues involved in making such a selection.

If there is a way to pin down $\mathrm{Set}$ I am also interested in using it in definitions of concepts like *locally small categories*.

My question is several-fold.

- Do we have a way of picking out a unique category to serve as $\mathrm{Set}$?
- Do we have a way of picking out a category that's unique up to isomorphism to serve as $\mathrm{Set}$?
- Is there a technical obstacle to *picking by fiat* an arbitrary category satisfying some rules to serve as $\mathrm{Set}$?
- Is it relevant that $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is not a complete theory?
- Is it relevant that $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is not categorical?

$\mathrm{ZFC}$ is a first order theory and therefore isn't categorical. $\mathrm{ZFC}$ is also not a complete theory.

If we assume $\mathrm{ZFC}$ in the background, then we can fashion many, many categories *explicitly* out of models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$.

Some of these categories, when thought of as models, will satisfy the same sentences. However, some of them will satisfy different sentences. The sentences that are independent of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ will be resolved in different ways in different models.

In addition, all of the categories fashioned from models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ necessarily have a domain that is *set-sized*. In our usual conception the category $\mathrm{Set}$ has a collection of objects that is not *set-sized*. This is sort of peculiar, but maybe it isn't that bad if we define notions like *locally small category* in terms of our choice of $\mathrm{Set}$ rather than in terms of the copy of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ that we have in the background.

Comment: Picking out of what?

Comment: Perhaps start by understanding something easier.  The theory for $(\mathbb N, +, \cdot, 0)$ is not categorical.  Does that mean there are multiple candidates for $\mathbb N$ ?  How do we pick one out?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I agree with the last paragraph. You can work with proper-class-sized models of ZFC, no problem.

Comment: @tomasz I think that depends on what you accept as foundational and are using in the background. Picking out of the category of categories or perhaps picking out of the categories fashioned out of explicit models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$. In my last paragraph, I was saying that non-proper-class-sized models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ are odd as candidates for $\mathrm{Set}$, but proper-class-sized ones are not weird.

Comment: @GEdgar, for arithmetic, we have a model that we call standard. I think we can pick it out using its cardinality and its order type but I am not positive.

Comment: The standard model for arithmetic is about as standard as the standard model of set theory. I don't think there is any fundamental difference between these two, at least not at this level of abstraction (well, apart from the fact that fixing a model of set theory fixes you a model of arithmetic, but not vice versa).

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do here.  In the usual foundational framework, there is absolutely no question of what "Set" means; it simply refers to the category whose objects are *all* sets and morphisms are all functions between them.  This has nothing whatsoever to do with models of ZFC.

Comment: The question of whether there is some way to categorically characterize Set as a special object inside the category of categories is an interesting one, but again has nothing to do with models of ZFC.

Comment: It seems you may be confusing the use of ZFC *in the background* as our foundation for mathematics (providing an axiomatization of what we mean by "set") with the notion of models of ZFC.  These are separate and you can do the first without ever caring about models of ZFC.  You may find [this answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/a/301061/75) helpful.

Comment: It depends on how you want your category theory to interact with your set theory.  The category **Sets** is your model of your set theory, whether you want to have things like urelement, Grothendieck universe/inaccessible cardinals, ... are up to you.

Comment: It may have been a mistake for me to mention models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$. I just wanted a ready-made source of categories that are not the obvious choice for $\mathrm{Set}$ but still work in some sense. The main thing I am interested in is how to pick out a specific category for $\mathrm{Set}$ and if there are technical issues involved in picking a specific category for $\mathrm{Set}$ rather than a category up to isomorphism. I also hedged my bets. Assuming that there isn't a good way to pick a unique category for $\mathrm{Set}$, I'm wondering if I'll run into trouble if I pick one arbitrarily.

Comment: What is the context in which you are trying to "pick" a category to be Set?  Why are you not just using the usual definition of Set as the category of all sets?

Comment: @EricWofsey Good point. I don't know. I assumed for some reason that assuming $\mathrm{ZFC}$ in the background did not give me the machinery to collect all my sets together and organize them into a category. If my question is incoherent, I can prune away the extraneous stuff about models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ and foundations and just ask about "what makes $\mathrm{Set}$ special category-theoretically in the category of categories".

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "category". If a category comprises a set of objects and a set of morphisms and etc. then you can't, because there is no set of all sets. But then there is no category of categories either.